# Iterate over JSON data in react app using reactjs

Tags: reactjs

I have to make PIE chart using json data. I made API from where am getting data in console and now I want the same data to be used in making pie chart but am not able to map it to get pie chart.
I am newbie to reactjs.

```
class Graph extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      pieConfigs: {},
    };
  }

  componentWillMount() {
    fetch("http://localhost:3010/analysis")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          pieConfigs: {
            type: "pie3d",
            width: "100%",
            height: "80%",
            dataFormat: "json",

            dataSource: {
              chart: {
                theme: "zune",
                canvasBgAlpha: "0",
                defaultcenterlabel: "Based on Purposes",
                showlegend: "0",
                bgAlpha: "0",
              },
              // Pie Data
              data: response,
            },
          },
        });
        console.log(response);
      });
  }

  render() {
    return <ReactFC {...this.state.pieConfigs} />;
  }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with "am not able to map it"? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: What does the data look like? What does the library, whatever it is you're using, expect?

Comment: `data: response` here make sure `response` is array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its because your **this.state.pieConfigs** render first before async call happened. Then it already render with empty state. You dont need to fetch api call in componentWillMount instead it should be done on componentDidMount

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import FusionCharts from "fusioncharts";
import Charts from "fusioncharts/fusioncharts.charts";
import ReactFC from "react-fusioncharts";
import FusionTheme from "fusioncharts/themes/fusioncharts.theme.fusion";

ReactFC.fcRoot(FusionCharts, Charts, FusionTheme);

class Chart extends Component {
  state = {
    loading: true,
    pieConfigs: {}
  };
  componentDidMount() {
    fetch("https://api.myjson.com/bins/19qk9d")
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(response => {
        this.setState({
          loading: false,
          pieConfigs: {
            type: "Pie3D",
            width: 600,
            height: 400,
            dataFormat: "json",
            dataSource: response
          }
        });
      });
  }
  render() {
    if (this.state.loading) return <>Loading..</>;
    return <ReactFC {...this.state.pieConfigs} />;
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<Chart />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here is working url : https://codesandbox.io/s/crimson-frog-1opqx

Comment: Hi Shubham Thank you for the help but when I made this changes in my code now also am not pie chart

Comment: Data is static of which I need to make Pie chart.

Comment: Can you host your code in codesandbox(https://codesandbox.io/) with that data as dummy json?? Its hard to tell from this. Data is static mean what?? If its coming from api then it is asynchronous

Comment: Sorry yes Its asynchronous

Comment: name  count_column
0                  car           337
1             radio/TV           280
2  furniture/equipment           181
3             business            97
4            education            59
5              repairs            22
6  domestic appliances            12
7      vacation/others            12

Comment: name and count_column is the header of the table and other are its values. Am getting data from api in this manner. now I want to use this data to create piechart.

Comment: Bro i need data in json format. Like normal constant (eg : {"test":"1"})

Comment: {
    "result": "car                    337\nradio/TV               280\nfurniture/equipment    181\nbusiness                97\neducation               59\nrepairs                 22\ndomestic appliances     12\nvacation/others         12\nName: purpose, dtype: int64"
}

Comment: I still dont understand your json data. But i made one demo example on codesandbox. Hope it helps you : https://codesandbox.io/s/kind-goodall-opm2k

Comment: Thank you so  much Shubham for your efforts. Its half working now but the only problem I am facing right now is that I have to push json values to piechart. I modified your code with my code please have a look in  it.

Comment: I have included json format also please have a look

Comment: You need host your json or api somewhere. You can not hit local server from codesandbox.

Comment: Thank you shubham for your efforts. Now its working